# temporary table is not created in procedure mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am creating a temporary table in a procedure

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS proc1
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE proc1()
BEGIN

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS temp_tbl1;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_tbl1
    (id int, name_c varchar(300));

    INSERT INTO temp_tbl1
    SELECT id, name_c FROM user_tbl;

END;
```

The procedure is compiled successfully. When i run the procedure as call proc1() it is giving an error message as unknown database 'test';

Can i use the temporary tables in procedures in mysql. I am using the mysql 5.1 server.

Comment: Yes you can use temporary table in procedure, kindly post the exact error here.

Comment: Even i am not able to create temporary table directly. This is not working in my system only. ERROR 1049 (42000): Unknown database 'test'. Is there any configuration need to be set.

Comment: Kindly drop db and then again create db.

Comment: I have created a new database and tried the temporary table. I have dropped and recreated the database and tried to create temporary table. In Both cases same error i am getting.

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot create any table you have a server configuration problem or a problem with permissions in the `data` directory (see `datadir` variable).

If the problem is limited to TEMPORARY tables, there's a [bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44706) in MySQL error reporting - the error message should say `"Unable to write to %tmpdir"` instead of `"Unknown database"`. Check what the MySQL variable `tmpdir` contains and create that directory. E.g. if it is `/usr/tmp`, do:

```
mkdir /usr/tmp
chmod 1777 /usr/tmp
```